# Presenting View Controller Error

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Trying to set a value from one view controller to another.

```
userAvatar = (presentingViewController as! OptionsPageViewController).newAvatar
```

Getting the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" 
and the error: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

This is the way I was taught to get data from other view controllers. For some reason it isn't working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error from the `as!` command.  What that means is that `presentingViewController` is not always an `OptionsPageViewController`, and you should conditionally unwrap it. Either like this:

```
if let presentingViewController = presentingViewController as? OptionsPageViewController {
    userAvatar = presentingViewController.newAvatar
} else {
    // do something to handle other controller types here
}
```

or with a `guard` if it represents a failure point in the method:

```
guard let presentingViewController = presentingViewController as? OptionsPageViewController else {
    return
}
userAvatar = presentingViewController.newAvatar
// continue with rest of method
```

or with conditional chaining, if `userAvatar` is an optional and nils are already being handled elsewhere:

```
userAvatar = (presentingViewController as? OptionsPageViewController)?.newAvatar
```

In general, you almost never want to force unwrap anything.  The only time you should use it is if you're absolutely 100% certain it will never be nil/the wrong type/etc., and even then you should think twice about it.

If you're 100% certain that it **should** be an `OptionsPageViewController`, double-check whatever code is supplying the value to make sure it's being initialized properly (but you should still unwrap it properly regardless).